# Does this fit as a counterexample?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Still learning about conditional statements, I'm now learning about Proofs in the same subject from here: [How to make this hypothesis in a negative form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280918/how-to-make-this-hypothesis-in-a-negative-form)

It's given that I should rewrite the statements these ways, where P is the first half of the statement and Q is the other half:

- **A.** P -> Q
- **B.** Q -> P
- **C.** P <-> Q

And the given statement is:

> It is an eagle, it's a bird.

So after some rewriting, it is given that I should make a counterexample of the statements if they are false. Both **B** and **C** are false, so I have to rewrite it with some counterexample.

So I rewrote **B** as:

> If it's a bird, then it could be an eagle.

As to the previous:

> If it's a bird, then it's an eagle.

I'm not sure if my counterexample fits well with the example statement. What other ways can I write my counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it's a bird, then it's an eagle.

is a way writing of B in English.  It's not the only way. Other possible answers could be

> It is a bird implies that it is an eagle

or

> All birds are eagles.

Note that "If it is a bird then it could be an eagle" is incorrect.  It doesn't express Q -> P  since P is "it is an eagle" not "It could be an eagle".

A counterexample is a specific bird that proves that this is not true

[image: Not an eagle]

Comment: I'm trying to figure what could fit for "If it's a bird, then it ______." Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean?  A counterexample is an example that proves a general fact wrong.   It needs to be specific.   "'A duck' is a counterexample to the claim that all birds are eagles."

Comment: Of course you still need to prove that this duck is a bird, and that this duck isn't an eagle.  That is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I follow what you're saying, but here's how I would go about it:

> **A.** If it is an eagle, then it is a bird. (*E* implies *B*)
> **B.** If it is a bird, then it is an eagle. (*B* implies *E*)
> **C.** A bird is the same thing as an eagle. (*E* implies *B* **and** *B* implies *E*)

(I'm not sure I have C right; it's been a while since I took a logic course. I understand the ⇔ operator to mean that the two statements are logically equivalent, is that right?)

A *counterexample* is not a rewriting of the statement; it is a real-world example that disproves the statement. So I would say:

Proposition **A** is correct.
A counterexample to **B** is: *A pigeon.* A pigeon is a bird, but is not an eagle. Therefore to say "If it is a bird, it is an eagle" must not be correct.
I believe the same counterexample could apply to **C.**

Comment: My problem is what I could use to make a counterexample for B and C, because they seem to be false. My answer in **C** would be "It's an eagle if and only if it's a bird."

Comment: @Water, a thing must be false for there to be a counterexample of it. What exactly are your instructions? A counterexample is not a rewriting of a statement, it is a *thing* (an *example*) that fits the structure of the statement but not the logic.

Comment: Rewrite the following statements given the illustrations (which are already listed in the question). If it's false, give a counterexample.

Comment: @Water, you must first rewrite each statement, *and then* — if the statement is not actually true — provide an example that disproves the statement.